# XML validation fails on Oracle for empty (string) element

Tags: c, oracle, xsd-validation

Validation of my XML document fails on Oracle (via oraxsd c library), but succeeds in other tools.

Oracle validation error:

LSX-00009: data missing for type "#simple"
LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "sequence", minimum is 1

For following XSD:

```
<xs:element name="AGREE" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="type7434"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="type7434">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>AGREE</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="70"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And following XML:

```
<AGREE/>
```

Same result for:
    `<AGREE></AGREE>`

Is the Oracle validation wrong in this case? If so, what would be the workaround?

I have little control over XSD, some control over XML and full access to validation process itself.

Oracle version: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, it looks like an error to me.  I wonder if the validator is making some eccentric distinction between sole tags and empty elements: does it also reject `<AGREE></AGREE>`?  Does it change the behavior if you add `<xs:minLength value="0"/>` to the declaration of type7434?

Comment: Yes, it rejects <AGREE></AGREE>, too. For the second part, I can't easily modify the final XSD (but I can modify it for testing purposes).